# Wolfram's axiom completeness

Tags: lo.logic, boolean-algebras

I have been reading Wolfram's A New Kind of Science, and as I was reading the section on systems of logic and axioms, I came across this axiom, for which all of the normal axioms of Boolean logic can be proved: ((a.b).c).(a.((a.c).a))=c, where . is the Nand (not and) operator. I believe it is true, but I would like to see a proof of some of the axioms of boolean logic from it.

I have tried to prove some of them myself, but I couldn't figure out how to prove lemmas from that axiom that are (even remotely) helpful.

Comment: I might be missing something, how can we deduce a=a from this single axiom?

Comment: @Wojowu: You have equational logic at your disposal.

Comment: Good luck with that.  Wolfram says he used Waldmeister to find proofs from the axioms he discussed, and those proofs have the ridiculous proportions shown on pp. 810-811:  http://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/page-810